# I am unable to execute a PHP file via NGiNX

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php-fpm

Here is the config I am calling from the browser:

```
location ~ ^/getfileinfo/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/editionspanda_conn/$1;
    }
```

Here is my config that calls the PHP file:

```
server {
    listen          127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name     127.0.0.1;
    root    /var/www/localhost/public/;
    include /var/nginx/general/php;

    location ~ ^/editionspanda_conn/(.*)$ {
            root            /var/www/EditionsPanda/livres.editionspanda.com/;
            try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

In the browser I am getting this error:

```
File not found.
```

In my error logs I get:

```
2013/09/09 22:12:20 [error] 8922#0: *2784 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /editionspanda_conn/name HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

- My version of NGiNX is: 1.2.7
- I am using Ubuntu 12.

With my other configs I have no problems accessing a PHP file and executing it.

Comment: First of all check that you have working socket at /var/run/php5-fpm.sock. Just ls -la /var/run/php5-fpm.sock should be enough.

Comment: I did a search for php5-fpm.sock and I could not find it. I used this command: find / -name php5-fpm.sock

Comment: But I did find php5-fpm.pid inside of /var/run/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Ubuntu's php5-fpm uses port 9000 by default. You can change it to use a socket by changing the listen line in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` from `127.0.0.1:9000` to `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.

Update:

If you need to use port 9000 then change this:

```
    location ~ ^/editionspanda_conn/(.*)$ {
            root            /var/www/EditionsPanda/livres.editionspanda.com/;
            try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```

to this:

```
    location ~ ^/editionspanda_conn/(.*)$ {
            root            /var/www/EditionsPanda/livres.editionspanda.com/;
            try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

Comment: I am using Magento, WordPress, and upload module of NGiNX and for these reason I had to use 127.0.0.1:9000 in www.conf.

Comment: Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
fastcgi_pass     unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Comment: Where? And in my main config I am already setup with 127.0.0.1:9000;